# How to run a java file from a different folder using linux terminal

Tags: java, linux

I want to run a compiled .java/.class file that is located in a subfolder from the folder I am currently working in.  I ran the command:

```
locate -br ^TheFileIWantToRun.java
```

so I know that the file is in the filepath:

```
/home/Me/Desktop/Folder1/Folder2/TheFileIWantToRun.java
```

I need to run this file from my current working directory:

```
/home/Me/Desktop/Folder1/
```

And I need to pass it a text file called test.

I have tried:

```
java -cp /home/Me/Desktop/Folder1/Folder2 TheFileIWantToRun test
```

But I get the error:

```
could not find or load the main class TheFileIWantToRun
```

Typically if the .java/.class file were in the same folder I would use:

```
java TheFileIWantToRun test
```

and this works.

How do I accomplish running a file from a different folder than the one I am in?  Thank you.

Comment: have you checked that your folder-structure represents your package structure defined in the .java file?

Comment: @ParkerHalo, I am not sure what you mean

Comment: @ParkerHalo no there is no package information

Comment: why not just `cd` into that directory, call the program there and give it the full path to the text file ?

Comment: @Marged the reason is that I am creating the test text file while in the current directory and I am trying to avoid going back and forth between directories.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the following :

```
java -cp /home/Me/Desktop/Folder1/Folder2 TheFileIWantToRun test
```

If test is not in the current directory then you should provide the full file path.

Comment: When I try the above it says could not find or load main class .home.Me.Desktop.Folder1.Folder2.TheFileIWantToRun

Comment: I have just edited my answer, I tried it my self and it worked for me, it's like the one you have already posted with your question.
Are you using any package naming for your class ?
Why don't you provide the Java file so we can take a look at it !

Comment: hmmm, it seems that both answers (including the one you posted previously) are the suggested route.  There maybe something specific to the system I am using that prevents me from doing this.  I am using a virtual machine that was set up for me, so I will check with that person to find if there is something else I need to do.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are a life saver!! you know that?